# Activity within library causes a NoClassDefFoundError when intent is started

Tags: android, android-activity, noclassdeffounderror, android-library

as the title says, I have an android project which has a library which is imported using the build.gradle. The library is imported from a local maven repository. The library is working perfectly fine for every single class without any issue. I've now tried created a new activity within this library and addad a reference to it within the manifest file. I've rebuilt and published to the maven repo successfully and cleaned my main project and starting the activity. Everything compiles fine but when I launch the activity I then get the following:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.MyCompany.Library.MyActivity`

I haven't been able to find anything from Google as most of what I've found is either focussed on Eclipse or import jar files library whereas as its a local maven the library is a .aar file.

Comment: No, I'm using Android Studio